# Hairdo and Haircut

Tags: differences

What is the difference in meaning between "Hairdo" and "Haircut"? In the dictionary into my native language it is written that "hairdo" must be used according to women. Does it mean that "haircut" can't be used in that way? I would like more explanation on this question.

Comment: I am not one hundred percent sure, but a hairdo gives me the idea of doing your hair (like braiding), a haircut is more the basic style of your hair, without you doing anything further to it.

Comment: A haircut suggests little more than cutting the hair to the desired shape.  A hairdo implies additional work to style the hair, for instance curling or colouring it.

Comment: Yes, women can get a haircut, although haircuts are sometimes more associated with men, and hairdos more associated with women. When I hear the word _hairdo_, though, I am reminded of 1960s beehives; I think the term _hairstyle_ is becoming more in vogue. [This Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+haircut%2Cher+hairdo%2Cher+haircut%2Chis+hairdo%2Cher+hairstyle&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) supports these general assertions, but they are nothing more vague generalities, and shouldn't be mistook for permanent rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "haircut" is when you get your hair cut; a "hairdo" is a "hairstyle". So if you do something with your hair with a comb, gel, wax, etc, you have a "hairdo". There is some cross-over though: you may get a haircut to achieve a new hairdo, but you can never say "haircut" without there having been some cutting.

Both men and women can have a "hairdo", but it is probably used more with reference to women.

Comment: I would say used *much* more with reference to women.  No male I know would admit to gettting a hairdo.

Comment: Yes, but "with reference to", not "by". These males you know can't stop people talking *about* their hairdos :p